# why I'm getting an error when on SDL_Init?

Tags: c++, sdl, init

when my code is:

```cpp
int WinMain(int argc, char **argv) {

    int SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    return 0;
}
```

it's working fine
but when my code is:

```cpp
int WinMain(int argc, char **argv) {

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        // nothing here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error:
`undefined reference to 'SDL_Init'`

I'm on VSC 1.32.1 window 10 mingw32 6.3.0

Comment: It means you forgot to link to your sdl libraries in the second example. The first example has nothing to do with sdl.

Comment: not sure if I was right in interpreting the question as "why the discrepancy?" If you merely want to fix the second, the proposed duplicate has the answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code you delcare an `int` called `SDL_Init`, lets change the names to make it more obvious:

```
int WinMain(int argc, char **argv) {
    int variable_name(some_value);    
}
```

In your second code you call a function:

```
int WinMain(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(some_function(some_value) < 0) { }
}
```

Thats why in the first you dont get an error, but in the second you do. Seems like there is no `some_function` aka `SDL_Init` defined, which can be caused by not linking corretly, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) for how to fix that.